# Upload image from Network

Tags: android, uiimageview, linker-errors, image-uploading

I can't download a picture from the Internet.

```
public class ImageUploadActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private final String myURL = "http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png";
    private ImageView uploadImage;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_upload);

        uploadImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.upload_image);
        bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(myURL);
        uploadImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

There are no exceptions, but my ImageView remains empty. I also tried to do this with AsyncTask, but the result is the same.

```
02-07 05:04:18.661  30323-30346/com.myapplication4.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
02-07 05:04:18.674  30323-30323/com.myapplication4.app D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
02-07 05:04:18.808  30323-30346/com.myapplication4.app I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/28/14, c33033c, Ia6306ec328
02-07 05:04:18.811  30323-30346/com.myapplication4.app I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-07 05:04:18.841  30323-30346/com.myapplication4.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: also call `connection.disconnect();` after getting Bitmap from stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Things here:

Use `https://` in your URL as below:

```
private final String myURL ="https://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png";
```

And since you are doing IO on Main thread of App, which is always strict NO-NO, your code is resulting into IOException.

If you debug this code , you will find that there is IOException on below line
`connection.connect();`

To Solve this, You should do IO Operation Using `AsyncTask`.

Below is the complete code to download the image using Given URL:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final String myURL ="https://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png";
    private ImageView uploadImage;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("MainActivity", "onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        uploadImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);        
        new MyDownloadTask().execute();        
    }


    class MyDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
          //display progress dialog.

     }
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {         
            try {
                URL url = new URL(myURL);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                uploadImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                connection.disconnect();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return null;         
     }
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         Log.e("MainActivity", "onPostExecute");         
     }
    }   
}
```

And below is the image after completing download shown in UI in my sample app.

[image]

Comment: I do exactly the same thing, but I picture is not loaded. Maybe the wrong configuration of the project?

Comment: check 2 more things. 1. I have this permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` 2. And in case if you do not see image loaded, just press HOME Key, and then Again open your App, because i too found that App is not getting autorefreshed after asynctask completes its execution

Comment: Still doesn't work. And there are no exceptions in the logcat. But how do you manage to interact with the GUI elements from the method doInBackground? In your NotificationBar something happens when downloading images? Maybe something was missing in my Android SDK?

Comment: I am setting the Imageview using  `uploadImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);` inside `doInBackground`. I am not using any other view in my layout (as I am just running a demo). Also not using any NotificationBar . Just copy-paste my code and see if you can fetch an image. I tested it on Android device with 4.2 Version with API Level 17

Comment: Oh! Indeed, it works fine on Android 4.2! But I do not understand why it does not work on my Android 5.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this library ([AQuery](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/)) to your project. This library is so lightweight and it simplified my life very much.

Use it as follows:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final String myURL ="https://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png";
private ImageView uploadImage;
Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AQuery aq = new AQuery(this);
    uploadImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);        
    aq.id(uploadImage).image(myUrl, false, true);
    //it caches the image so the second time you try to download the image it reads from cache file and  it is gonna be so fast
}
}
```

Comment: This is a test job, I do not have to use third-party libraries.

Comment: But this is also a useful library. In the future, I'll know about it :)